# Is there something like "Shows Touch on Highlight" (iPhone Interface Builder) on Android Platform?

Tags: iphone, android, button

I use lots of transparent buttons in my apps. The button graphical area is on the background.

> On iPhone there is
>
> > "Shows Touch on Highlight"

which is really super to easily get a good touch effect without lots of work.

Is there something like this on Android? So far I found

> color scheme changes of the
>   Button-Text or the buttom area on
>   Android

which in most cases doesn't really look good since the "button" area on the graphics is not really a rectangle. The "Shows on highlight"-effect on iPhone seems to be the perfect solution. It would be nice to also have that on android. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to add the highlights yourself in photoshop or gimp and use a state-list drawable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: yes thank you, I also started to use this, but with transparent buttons it does not really work well....